# Nocite(*) doesn't work if you literally don't cite anything?

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, biber

I want to literally just list all the references of a .bib file. I am not going to cite a single reference - I just want to generate a reference list. Is this not possible?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,titlepage,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text.    
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

I keep getting undefined control sequence no matter what I do. Do you have to cite in order to get this to work?

More info: I am doing LuaLaTeX, biber, LuaLaTeX - but I can never progress further because it keeps giving undefined control sequence.

Comment: Your sample document fails because you haven't loaded the `csquotes` package. Since you don't show the error I can only guess that's the same error you're getting in your actual document.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see anything that said csquotes was required for this to work. Maybe I just didn't look hard enough. Thanks again!

Comment: `csquotes` isn't technically required, but the `biblatex-examples.bib` file uses some commands from it, and so that's why it's needed in this example. But it's generally a good idea to always load it when using `biblatex`.

Comment: For me this document just produces three errors. All about `\enquote*`, which is a `csquotes` command. As Alan Munn says, usually `csquotes` is not a requirement (and only warmly recommended), but in this case you need to load it in order to be able to process all entries without error. If you call `\nocite{*}` on a `.bib` file that does not use `csquotes` commands, you should get no such issue.